# how to extract signs of numbers correctly from a pandas string column

Tags: python, pandas

I have an data_dict pandas dataframe with field_names and valid_values (range). I want to convert the valid values to lower_limit and upper_limit.

| field_names | valid_values | lower_limit | upper_limit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Var1 | 0-9990 | 0 | 9990 |
| Var2 | -9990-9999990 | -9990 | 9999990 |
| Var3 | -999999990-999999990 | -999999990 | 999999990 |
| Var4 | 0-999999990 | 0 | 999999990 |

The code below extracts upper_limit correctly but misses out the negative sign of the lower limits

```
data_dict.valid_values.str.extractall(r'(\d+)').unstack()
```

The code below extracts upper_limit correctly but misses out the negative sign of the lower limits

The code below works correctly for lower limit, but adds the '-' delimited to upper limit

```
data_dict.valid_values.str.extractall(r'([+-]\d+)').unstack()
```

Please suggest how to extract the lower and upper limits correctly. Thank you.

Comment: can you have something like '-2--1' for (-2,-1)?

Answer (score 2):

You can split values by last `-` by [`Series.str.rsplit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html) if always `upper_limit` is positive:

```
cols = ['lower_limit','upper_limit']
data_dict[cols] = data_dict.valid_values.str.rsplit('-', expand=True, n=1)
print (data_dict)
  field_names          valid_values lower_limit upper_limit
0        Var1                0-9990           0        9990
1        Var2         -9990-9999990       -9990     9999990
2        Var3  -999999990-999999990  -999999990   999999990
3        Var4           0-999999990           0   999999990
```

Comment: I will check this out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an optional `-` in your regex with `-?`.

**This enables you to also have a negative number in the second part.**

```
df['valid_values'].str.extract(r'(?P<lower_limit>-?\d+)-(?P<upper_limit>-?\d+)')
```

output:

```
  lower_limit upper_limit
0           0        9990
1       -9990     9999990
2  -999999990   999999990
3           0   999999990
```

Short version:

```
df[['lower_limit', 'upper_limit']] = df['valid_values'].str.extract(r'(-?\d+)-(-?\d+)')
```

output:

```
  field_names           valid_values lower_limit upper_limit
0       Var1                 0-9990            0        9990
1       Var2          -9990-9999990        -9990     9999990
2       Var3   -999999990-999999990   -999999990   999999990
3       Var4            0-999999990            0   999999990
```

Comment: Thanks. I will check this out.